# Manage your applications doesn't appear in Itunes Connect panel

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I need to upload an app to iTunes store. have the certificates, provisioning profiles but when I logged in to iTunes the menu "Manage your applications" doesn't appear.

Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't have sufficient permission for "Manage your applications" in iTunes Connect. Please ask your agent of developer profile to give you the permission as admin.

Comment: but I logged in with my e-mail. And the Developer Programm's account is mine. This is the Enterprise programm...why is my account as 'sale'? I'm the owner...

Comment: Yes I did not ever use the enterprise account of apple but I think Enterprise account for in house app distribution. For that you don't need iTunes connect "manage application" section for uploading app to iTunes that's why it's missing.

Comment: That was because I already have a account linked with this e-mail. I 'dislinked' of the other account and it worked